# Typescript using the incorrect type with jest when there are multiple available

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, js-cookie

I am new to typescript and noticed a behaviour I wasn't expecting. When I go to mock a named import with the `js-cookie` package, it mocks a particular instance of the property, but incorrectly chooses the correct type to use.

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie"
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils"

jest.mock("js-cookie")
const mockedCookies = mocked(Cookies, true)

beforeEach(() => {
  mockedCookies.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => "123")
})

it("SampleTest", () => {
  //this line throws an error as it is using a difference interface to check against
  mockedCookies.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => undefined)
  //continue test...
}
```

In the `@types/js-cookies` there are two definitions for this and it always uses the `get()` version when I reference it as `mockCookie.get.<some-jest-function>`. Hence, I get typescript errors saying `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.`.

```js
/**
* Read cookie
*/
get(name: string): string | undefined;

/**
* Read all available cookies
*/
get(): {[key: string]: string};
```

I can fix this by always redeclaring the `jest.fn()` every time, but would prefer to use the handy jest functions (like mockImplementationOnce).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to enforce which `get` type to use?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps but you may use `mockedCookies.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({}))` as of now to get rid of this error.

Updated:
After some testing, I see that these mock functions are stored in dictionary style format. The last function with same name always replace the previous ones.

If you try to move `get(name: string)` below `get()` from 'js-cookie', you will see that this error is gone.
So there is no way to get specific function with same name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your use-case, but you may do better not using jest mocks and instead use jest's jsdom environment. You can then set up your environment using js-cookie's methods.

In your example, you can run `Cookies.remove(<cookie name>);` as setup, then when you run `Cookies.get(<cookie name>)`, you should get `undefined`, no? You do have to be careful about state persisting between tests, but you have to do that in the mock version of this anyway.

I tested jsdom's implementation for a couple simple cases, but I have no idea how thorough their mock is for more advanced use cases involving multiple domains, etc.